# Effective transaction management

Tags: c#, sql, queue, task-parallel-library, sql-server-2014

I am looking for advice on a design to effectively allow scalability and reduce contention for my requirement:

My current environment is using messaging architecture with queues , windows services and sql 2014, c# .net etc. we have a requirement to persist data into a staging table, do some validation on this data and then once validation is complete load the data into a final table and do some more calculations on the data in the final table, once this work flow is complete then clear those specific data rows from the staging table. The load into the staging table can be a few thousand rows per load. Each message in the queue initiates this process and we expect there to be a burst of around 1000 to 2000 messages in a short periods throughout the day.
Due to the nature of using queues and trying to build a scalable architecture, within our window service we want to read a batch of messages of a queue say 10 per read, run a couple of threads in parallel one per message with each thread owning a transaction that is responsible for loading the staging staging table, validating in process the staging data - imagine mapping, enriching etc. and the shifting the data to the final target table, doing some calculations on the final table and then deleting the relative rows in the staging table. Sounds like lots of contention!
Both tables will have a unique index across 3 columns and a PK, but not neccesarily 1 to 1 relationship. Around 20 columns in staging and 15 in final table so not very wide... I would also prefer to not use msdtc as we will be using multiple sql connections. I realize in 2008 Microsoft introduced lightweight sql transaction to reduce the burden.

I have not looked into locking on columnar store tables and would prefer not to use dirty reads as a hack.

If you have successfully done something similar to this before I would really like to hear your comments! PS please note SQL 2014, C#, TPL.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe I do not get the concept correctly, but the SQL Server's internal mechanisms can share the load quite well on their own... Normally one should not try to trick this out... Would you please describe what is done in C# and what is done in your RDBMS. How is the data coming in and where is written to?

Comment: The data will be coming from disk, read into a list of objects in code then pushed into the staging table, normally the above scenario wouldn't be an issue, but as its going to be running in parallel in loops I'm forseeing some performance issues. We are looking at TVP or bcp to persist the data. a scenario will be write 1000 rows, read out through those rows do some validation in code, then write output from code into final table then read through those rows and do some calculations, the delete the rows in the staging table, this is all done with say 10 threads doing the same thing.

Comment: I have actually being toying now with creating a logical transaction in code using a very basic state machine and a guid as a key, thus not locking the tables at all. Of course we will test with ms sql and normal transactions to see the numbers...